# What is the F# equivalent of C# named arguments?

Tags: c#, .net, f#, yaml

In the DotNetYaml sample code I'm looking at, there's a C# construct:

```
var deserializer = new Deserializer(namingConvention: new CamelCaseNamingConvention());
var order = deserializer.Deserialize<Order>(input);
```

What is the equivalent F# code? I've tried

```
let deserializer = new Deserializer(namingConvention=new CamelCaseNamingConvention())
deserializer.Deserialize<Meta>(input)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a C# library that defines optional parameters, then you can use the syntax you are using in your question. To quickly show that's the case, I compiled the following C# code as a library:

```
using System;

namespace Demo {
  public class MyClass {
    public static void Foo(int first, string second = "foo", string third = "bar") { }
  }
}
```

You can reference this and use it from F# as follows:

```
open Demo
MyClass.Foo(1, third="hi")
```

I tried to do this with `YamlDotNet` which, I guess, is the library that you were using, but I get an error that the `Deserializer` class does not have `namingConvention` as an argument, so my guess would be that you are probably using a different version of the library than you are thinking (or perhaps, my guess of what library you're using was wrong...).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll cut a ticket to the folks owning the library about the example being out of date.

Comment: In the meantime, it's just the first argument; there is no need to "name it". So it's new Deserializer(new CamelCaseNamingConvention())